# How to get list of values from ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm populating `ListView` from Firestore and I need to get list of all documents id displayed in `ListView` on press of a button. Here is a simplified example

```
class MaterialScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
      {'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'},
      {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(list[index]['name']),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Print all ids'),
            onPressed: () {print();}, //<-- how to get all list ids displayed in ListView
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list variable and add id's in list when you build listview.

In addition to that it is always good to create variable outside of build method because it will create new variable every time whenever build method rebuild. i mean setState is called.

Following code help you more to understand.

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}
  ];
  List<int> _ids = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _ids.clear();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  _ids.add(list[index]['id']);
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(list[index]['name']),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Print all ids'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(_ids.toString());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ohh... Thanks.. Such a obvious solution... :)